# Утечка памяти связанная с EditText

Tags: android, kotlin

Есть проект, в котором начал ловить утечку с помощью `LeakCanary`, что бы разобраться уменьшил код до минимума. На данном этапе не пропала. Связана с `EditText`, так как если его убрать пропадает. При создании нового проекта с идентичным кодом утечка не обнаруживается. Утечка обнаруживается как в последней стабильной версии `LeakCanary`, так как и в версии 2.0-beta-3

Экран с утечкой:

```
class LoginActivity : Activity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login)

        findViewById<View>(R.id.buttonLogin).setOnClickListener {
            val intent = Intent(this.applicationContext, MainActivity::class.java)
            startActivity(intent)
            finish()
        }
    }
}
```

`activity_login.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editLogin"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/buttonLogin"
        android:layout_width="250dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:text="Login"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/editLogin" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Второй экран содержит просто текст.

Утечка:

```
09-04 20:51:51.344 6524-6609 D/LeakCanary: HeapAnalysisSuccess(heapDumpFile=/storage/emulated/0/Download/leakcanary-ua.artem.template/2019-09-04_20-50-04_984.hprof, createdAtTimeMillis=1567619511339, analysisDurationMillis=98565, applicationLeaks=[ApplicationLeak(className=ua.artem.template.LoginActivity, leakTrace=
    ┬
    ├─ java.lang.Thread
    │    Leaking: UNKNOWN
    │    Thread name: 'Studio:InputCon'
    │    GC Root: Java local variable
    │    ↓ thread Thread.<Java Local>
    │                    ~~~~~~~~~~~~
    ├─ com.android.tools.profiler.support.event.InputConnectionWrapper
    │    Leaking: UNKNOWN
    │    ↓ InputConnectionWrapper.mTarget
    │                             ~~~~~~~
    ├─ com.android.internal.widget.EditableInputConnection
    │    Leaking: UNKNOWN
    │    ↓ EditableInputConnection.mTargetView
    │                              ~~~~~~~~~~~
    ├─ android.widget.EditText
    │    Leaking: YES (View.mContext references a destroyed activity)
    │    mContext instance of ua.artem.template.LoginActivity with mDestroyed = true
    │    View#mParent is set
    │    View#mAttachInfo is null (view detached)
    │    View.mWindowAttachCount = 1
    │    ↓ EditText.mContext
    ╰→ ua.artem.template.LoginActivity
    ​     Leaking: YES (EditText↑ is leaking and Activity#mDestroyed is true and ObjectWatcher was watching this)
    ​     key = 4736cc9c-2017-41ae-a861-89fbb71a8ead
    ​     watchDurationMillis = 6586
    ​     retainedDurationMillis = 1582
    , retainedHeapByteSize=23141)], libraryLeaks=[])
```

[Исходники](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1oOp6OcChOiFOl_vKpmufdj09pPgdk-aB/view?usp=sharing) мини проекта на всякий случай.

Comment: В коде у вас ошибок нет. Получается, что это бага андроида или либы для определения утечек. Может быть в ConstraintLayout. Попробуйте убрать привязки оного из EditText. Если не поможет - просто забейте.

Comment: @ЮрийСПб не помогает. Вероятно так и есть, ошибка андроид или библиотеки.

Comment: Подкину ещё два подозреваемых. Kotlin RT - попробуйте сделать ту же активность на java. IDE: в debug версию может быть внедрён лишний код для поддержки некоторых функций IDE - попробуйте потестить на релизной сборке.

Comment: @woesss Хорошая идея, но на java та же ошибка. LeackCanary для релизной сборки пока ещё не настроил.

Comment: Значит проделки IDE. Я вот пригляделся получше и пакет класса `com.android.tools.profiler.support.event.InputConnectionWrapper` явно намекает на профайлер. Скорее всего на релизе проблема отпадёт.

Comment: @woesss Магия. Спасибо. Отключил Profiling в конфигурации запуска и ошибка пропала. По желанию можете добавить эту информацию в качестве ответа.